# Prove that graph on $n$ vertices has at most $n$ cuts of size one

Tags: graph-theory

Can you please help me prove the following claim?

> Any graph on $n$ vertices has at most $n$ cuts of size one.

I tried to use induction on $n$ (assume the hypothesis holds true for $k-1$ and add one vertex) but I fail to get any strong argument from the induction hypothesis.

I would also appreciate help on the following related claim:

> Any graph with $m$ edges has a cut of size at least $1/2 \cdot m$

Definition of cut:

> $C \subseteq E(G)$ is cut if there exists $X \subseteq V(G)$ such that C consists of all edges in $G$ that have one end in $X$ and the other outside of $X$. $G$ doesn't have to be connected.

Comment: A cut has a set of vertices $X$ associated to it. A cut of size one has one vertex associated to it and two cuts don't share the same same $X$ associated to them.

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more? I see claim from my question follows from your claim but I have the same problems with proving your claim as with the claim in my question.

Comment: I actually think there can't be more than $n - 1$ cuts of size one, which is only attained by a tree - but I might be wrong.  Do you have an example of a graph with $n$ such cuts ?

Comment: @Andrew123321 What I said, is just reading the definition of cut.

Comment: @ManuelLafond: Cycle on $n$ vertices has $n$ cuts of size 1.

Comment: OK then I misunderstood the definition.  Could you tell me what's wrong in this : take $C_4$, the cycle of order 4 with vertices $a,b,c,d$ that form the $abcda$ cycle.  Then $ab$ should be a cut of size one.  But I can't find $X$.  Say $a \in X$ and $b \in \overline{X}$.  Then $c$ must be in $\overline{X}$ or otherwise $bc$ would cross the partition (but $ab$ is the only crossing edge).  But then, $d \in \overline{X}$ as well, or else $cd$ crosses.  But here, $ad$ crosses and so there can't be a cut of size one with $ab$.

Comment: @ManuelLafond You're right, that would imply cycle doesn't have any cut of size 1 which implies that tree is the edge case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there can't be more than $n - 1$ cuts of size one.  Suppose there are at least $n$ cuts of size one.
Let $E'$ be the set of edges included in a cut of size one, and let $G' = (V, E')$, i.e. the graph $G$ in which we only keep the edges of $E'$.

Since $E' \geq n$, $G'$ has a cycle $v_1v_2 \ldots v_kv_1$.  Now, $G'$ has a cut of size one containing only $v_1v_2$ (which is also a cut of size one in $G$).  Say $v_1 \in X, v_2 \in \overline{X}$.  But $v_1v_2 \ldots v_kv_1$ is a cycle so ...

End of the hint :)

As for the other problem, induction should work here.  Find a base case, then look at $G' = G-v$ (for some arbitrary vertex $v$) in the induction step.
Here, $G'$ has a cut with partitions $X$ and $\overline{X}$ with at least half of its edges.  Now we need to put back $v$ in either $X$ or $\overline{X}$.  One of them has at least half of the neighbors of $v$, and from then you should be able to make the appropriate choice (and fill in the details).